# Get a dictionary from a list of multiple lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From a given list with multiple lists I need to get them into a dictionary. This is the list of lists:

```
my_table = [["Account Manager", "Name", "BP", "Contact", "Quote Name", "Type", "Status", "Total"],
            ["bubble", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["rose", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["purple", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["dark", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["star", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["asmr", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],]
```

I tried this code and it gives me the keys correctly as I want them (the first list (`["Account Manager", "Name", "BP", "Contact", "Quote Name", "Type", "Status", "Total"]`)) as the keys but then it gives me only one other list from all the lists as the value .

The code:

```
dict_from_table = {}
for key in my_table[0]:
  for value in my_table:
    dict_from_table[key] = value


print(dict_from_table)
```

The result it gives me back is:

```
{'Account Manager': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total'], 'Name': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total'], 'BP': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total'], 'Contact': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total'], 'Quote Name': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total'], 'Type': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total'], 'Status': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total'], 'Total': ['asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'stat', 'total']}
```

which is ok but it is only the last list from all the lists .

I want the output to be with the same keys but to give me every list from my big list . So first time the keys with the list 1 and then the same keys with the list 2 ...

Comment: Every key in a dictionary has to be unique, so every time you assign something to a key, the value is replaced with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what is the desired output, but if it is each value on
the following lists in a list under the key on the same position:`

```
dict_from_table = {}
for position, key in enumerate(my_table[0]):
  dict_from_table[key] = []
  for value_row in my_table[1:]:
    dict_from_table[key].append(value_row[position])

print(dict_from_table)
```